# How to implement a "Deep Link" on Ajax calls over ZF?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, deep-linking

I feel the need to allow the browser back button to work, as well to allow the users to bookmark what they see.

I'm not versatile on Zend routes but, I cannot change that for the moment.

This is the ajax implementation approach that I'm using:

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('blank');
        $logger = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('Log');
        $logger->debug('AJAX Call');
    }
}


public function indexAction()
{
    // render the default page
}

public function somethingelseAction()
{
    // do something else render something.
}
```

}

Have my initial view render with a target div, as well as some links... Here's my index.phtml:

```
<h1>Tests...</h1>
        <a class="ajaxloader"
            href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=> 'test', 'action' => 'speed'), null, true);?>">Speed</a>
        <a class="ajaxloader"
            href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=> 'test', 'action' => 'somethingelse'), null, true);?>">Something Else</a>
        <div id="testresults">
        <h1>Default stuff to show.</h1>
        </div>
```

Some jQuery code to attach to these 'ajaxloader' links and target the results to the 'testresults' div.

```
$(function() {
$('.ajaxloader').click(function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.hash = target;
    $('#testresults').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // complete fadeout, load new content while it's hiding!
        $.ajax( {
            url : target,
            success : function(data) {
                $('#testresults').html(data);
                $('#testresults').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
})
});
```

**How can a deep link be implemented here?**

Thanks a lot,
MEM

PS - Good credits for this implementation goes to Darryl E. Clarke.
I can take the bad ones.

Comment: Anyone else read the question and think 'well, it'd be easier if you could use the Axiom of Choice'? No? Okay, just me.

Comment: @Tom Anderson - I would be glad with a: "look here" and "here". At this time however, I'm just lost. However, of course, I'm not refering to a dummy: "look on google". The point is, for this specific scenario, or, at least similar, I seem to have found nothing.

Comment: I wish i could help - i'm afraid i haven't a clue :(.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jquery but to me, everything looks ok. You want to load some content from your zf-application with ajax. What is/is not working here? :)

Comment: Thanks ;)  And PS. the `window.location.hash` is part of the solution to your question.  I just haven't finished the solution.

Comment: @All: thanks again. :) I will have a look into window.location.hash and see if I find some clues. @Fge - The problem here, is that I can't book mark my "ajax page" neither make the back browser button to work. I see this, http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/ but I don't have a clue neither about how it works and how it be of any use here. I'm just asking for some clues here. K. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

For the deep linking: I had to do the same thing (our code looks almost identical!) and after a while found [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/). There is a problem with IE, though. One of the functions causes it to stop working. As far as I can tell, I'm not using that feature so I've just got it to return instead of doing whatever it is doing. In the current version (1.3.1) it is the function at line 77 (_search = function(el)). Like I said, I just placed a return at the top of the function and it all works nicely now.

As for routes... [The documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) should be your first port of call.
What I do for routes, is in my bootstrap file, create an _init function and do something like:

```
$this->bootstrap('frontController');
/* @var $frontcontroller Zend_Controller_Front */
$frontcontroller = $this->getResource('frontController');
$router = $frontcontroller->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'page',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('(.*)\.html',
        array('controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'page',
            'module' => 'default'),
            array('page' => 1),
        '%s.html'
    )
);
```

But put together your own routes to suit your needs (for example you probably don't want to use regex routes).